# How to reach object properties from another class in Python

Tags: python, properties

I'm familiar with other oop languages but new to Python.
i wanted to know if this is the right way to define properties in a class

```
class TwoInputParameters(object):
def __init__(self,firstParameter,secondParameter,operator):
    self.firstParameter= firstParameter
    self.secondParametr = secondParameter
    self.operator = operator
```

my second question is - how can i reach this properties when given an object of the TwoInputParameters type as a method's input?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Class attributes can be accessed using `getattr (object, attribute_name)` http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the right way to define a *class* and some *attributes* in its `__init__()` method -- in Python we commonly use the term attributes and not properties for [names following a dot](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

To reference attributes just use the pattern `objectName` `.` `attributeName`:

```
>>> myObject = TwoInputParameters("hello", "foo", 42) #craete a new instance of the TwoInputParameters class
>>> print(myObject.firstParameter) #reference the firstParameter attibute
   "hello"

>>> myObject.secondParametr = "bar" #change an attribute
>>> print(myObject.firstParameter) 
   "bar"
```